# How can I “translate” a statistical model defined on paper to the computer using R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian, hidden-markov-models

> I have initially posted this question on `stats.stackexchange.com`,
> but it was closed due to being focused on programming. Hopefully, I
> can get any help here.

I will not put many theoretical details here to make it simple, but my final goal is to implement a Hidden Markov Model using `R`.

Although I am fine with the theoretical model construction, when I tried to implement it, I realized that I do not know basic things about computational statistics. My question goes into this direction.

Let [image: $X$] and [image: $Y$] be random variables such that [image] and [image: $Y|X \sim \mathcal{N}(x, \sigma^2)$], with [image: $p \in [0, 1]$] and [image: $\sigma^2 \in [0, +\infty)$]. If [image: $\pi(\cdot)$] denotes *distribution*, **how can I compute**

[image]

**using** `R`?

I mean, what is the exact meaning of these distributions (one discrete and one continuous) multiplication? How can I do this using `R`? The answer is obviously a function of [image: $x$], but how is it represented in my code?

Is there any change if [image: $Y|X$] is also discrete? For instance, [image], with [image: $q \in [0, 1]$]. How it would affect the implemented code?

I know my questions are not very specific, but I am very lost on how to start. My goal with this question is understanding how I can "translate" what I have written in paper to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Translation

The equations describe how to compute the probability distribution of `X` given an observation of `Y=y` and values for parameters `p` and `sigma`. Ultimately, you want to implement a function `p_X_given_Y` that takes a value of `Y` and returns a probability distribution for `X`. A good place to start is to implement the two functions used in the RHS of the expression. Something like,

```r
p_X <- function (x, p=0.5) { switch(as.character(x), "0"=p, "1"=1-p, 0) }

p_Y_given_X <- function (y, x, sigma=1) { dnorm(y, x, sd=sigma) }
```

Note that `p` and `sigma` are picked arbitrarily here. These functions can then be used to define the `p_X_given_Y` function:

```r
p_X_given_Y <- function (y) {
  # numerators: for each x \in X
  ps <- sapply(c("0"=0,"1"=1), 
               function (x) { p_X(x) * p_Y_given_X(y, x) })

  # divide out denominator
  ps / sum(ps)
}
```

which can be used like:

```
> p_X_given_Y(y=0)
#         0         1 
# 0.6224593 0.3775407

> p_X_given_Y(y=0.5)
#   0   1 
# 0.5 0.5 

> p_X_given_Y(y=2)
#         0         1 
# 0.1824255 0.8175745
```

These numbers should make intuitive sense (given `p=0.5`): `Y=0` is more likely to come from `X=0`, `Y=0.5` is equally likely to be `X=0` or `X=1`, etc.. This is only one way of implementing it, where the idea is to return the "distribution of X", which in this case is simply a named numeric vector, where the names ("0", "1") correspond to the support of X, and the values correspond to the probability masses.

Some alternative implementations might be:

- a `p_X_given_Y(x,y)` that also takes a value for `x` and returns the corresponding probability mass
- a `p_X_given_Y(y)` that returns another function that takes an `x` argument and returns the corresponding probability mass (i.e., the probability mass function)